# ORA-00907 missing right parenthesis In Crystal - Works in Oracle Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, crystal-reports, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have an issue with a query, it works fine in Oracle Developer with `{?Month}` replaced with `'2015-01-01'` but in Crystal it is giving me the error `ORA-00907 missing right parenthesis` when using the query below.

**Parameter**

> Parameter Name: Month
>
> Prompting text: Enter Month
>
> Value Type: String (also tried date)
>
> Default Value: 2015-01-01 00:00:00AM

**Code**

```
SELECT /*+ ordered_predicates */
ACTIVE_SEPARATE.WO_NO, ACTIVE_SEPARATE.MCH_CODE,
(SELECT DISTINCT CASE WHEN MCH_CODE LIKE '%-%' THEN TRIM(SUBSTR(MCH_CODE, 0, INSTR(MCH_CODE, '-')-1)) ELSE MCH_CODE END FROM ACTIVE_SEPARATE ACTIVE_SEPARATE_SUB WHERE ACTIVE_SEPARATE.MCH_CODE = ACTIVE_SEPARATE_SUB.MCH_CODE) AS MCH_CODE_TRIM,
(SELECT DISTINCT CASE WHEN MCH_NAME LIKE '%-%' THEN TRIM(SUBSTR(MCH_NAME, 0, INSTR(MCH_NAME, '-')-1)) ELSE MCH_NAME END FROM EQUIPMENT_FUNCTIONAL WHERE ACTIVE_SEPARATE.MCH_CODE = EQUIPMENT_FUNCTIONAL.MCH_CODE) AS MCH_NAME_TRIM,
MCH_TYPE, ACTIVE_SEPARATE.REQUIRED_START_DATE, ACTIVE_SEPARATE.ERR_DESCR,
(24 * ((REAL_F_DATE) - (REQUIRED_START_DATE))) as BREAKDOWN_HOURS,
(100 - ((((last_day(to_date({?Month}, 'yyyy-mm-dd'))) -  trunc(to_date({?Month}, 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'month'))*24) + 24) - (( (REAL_F_DATE) - (REQUIRED_START_DATE))* 24)) / ((24 * ((last_day(to_date({?Month}, 'yyyy-mm-dd'))) - trunc(to_date({?Month}, 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'month'))) + 24) AS PERCENTAGE_AVAILABILITY
FROM ACTIVE_SEPARATE
RIGHT JOIN EQUIPMENT_FUNCTIONAL ON EQUIPMENT_FUNCTIONAL.MCH_CODE = (SELECT DISTINCT CASE WHEN MCH_CODE LIKE '%-%' THEN TRIM(SUBSTR(MCH_CODE, 0, INSTR(MCH_CODE, '-')-1)) ELSE MCH_CODE END FROM ACTIVE_SEPARATE ACTIVE_SEPARATE_SUB WHERE ACTIVE_SEPARATE.MCH_CODE = ACTIVE_SEPARATE_SUB.MCH_CODE)
WHERE ERR_CLASS = '001'
AND MCH_TYPE IS NOT NULL
AND ACTIVE_SEPARATE.REQUIRED_START_DATE BETWEEN
(trunc(to_date({?Month}, 'yyyy-mm-dd'),'month')
AND
last_day({?Month}))

UNION

SELECT /*+ ordered_predicates */
HISTORICAL_SEPARATE.WO_NO, HISTORICAL_SEPARATE.MCH_CODE,
case when (TRIM(SUBSTR(HISTORICAL_SEPARATE.MCH_CODE, 0, INSTR(HISTORICAL_SEPARATE.MCH_CODE, '-')-1))) is null then HISTORICAL_SEPARATE.MCH_CODE else(TRIM(SUBSTR(HISTORICAL_SEPARATE.MCH_CODE, 0, INSTR(HISTORICAL_SEPARATE.MCH_CODE, '-')-1))) end as MCH_CODE_TRIM,
case when (TRIM(SUBSTR(EQUIPMENT_FUNCTIONAL.MCH_NAME, 0, INSTR(EQUIPMENT_FUNCTIONAL.MCH_NAME, '-')-1))) is null then EQUIPMENT_FUNCTIONAL.MCH_NAME else(TRIM(SUBSTR(EQUIPMENT_FUNCTIONAL.MCH_NAME, 0, INSTR(EQUIPMENT_FUNCTIONAL.MCH_NAME, '-')-1))) end as MCH_NANME_TRIM,
MCH_TYPE,  HISTORICAL_SEPARATE.REQUIRED_START_DATE, HISTORICAL_SEPARATE.ERR_DESCR,
(24 * ((REAL_F_DATE) - (REQUIRED_START_DATE))) as BREAKDOWN_HOURS,
(100 - ((((last_day(to_date({?Month}, 'yyyy-mm-dd'))) -  trunc(to_date({?Month}, 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'month'))*24) + 24) - (( (REAL_F_DATE) - (REQUIRED_START_DATE))* 24)) / ((24 * ((last_day(to_date({?Month}, 'yyyy-mm-dd'))) - trunc(to_date({?Month}, 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'month'))) + 24) AS PERCENTAGE_AVAILABILITY
FROM HISTORICAL_SEPARATE
RIGHT JOIN EQUIPMENT_FUNCTIONAL ON EQUIPMENT_FUNCTIONAL.MCH_CODE = (SELECT DISTINCT CASE WHEN MCH_CODE LIKE '%-%' THEN TRIM(SUBSTR(MCH_CODE, 0, INSTR(MCH_CODE, '-')-1)) ELSE MCH_CODE END FROM HISTORICAL_SEPARATE HISTORICAL_SEPARATE_SUB WHERE HISTORICAL_SEPARATE.MCH_CODE = HISTORICAL_SEPARATE_SUB.MCH_CODE)
WHERE ERR_CLASS = '001'
AND MCH_TYPE IS NOT NULL
AND HISTORICAL_SEPARATE.REQUIRED_START_DATE BETWEEN
(trunc(to_date({?Month}, 'yyyy-mm-dd'),'month')
AND
last_day({?Month}))
```

Comment: Did you try replacing the month parameter with an actual date literal and see what happens?

Comment: where are you trying the query? on database or using crystal reports?

Comment: @OldProgrammer Yeh it works if i use '2015-01-01' instead of month in crystal.

Comment: @Siva As i said above it works in oracle developer but not in crystal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your premise is wrong; it doesn't work in SQL Developer. If you copy-and-paste your query and replace `{?Month}` with `'2015-01-01'`, you get the same ORA-00907 error, reported on line 14 column 1, which is the `AND` on its own.

This:

```
BETWEEN
(trunc(to_date({?Month}, 'yyyy-mm-dd'),'month')
AND
last_day({?Month}))
```

has the parentheses in the wrong place - you're trying to do `between (x and y)` which isn't the correct syntax. It should be:

```
BETWEEN
trunc(to_date({?Month}, 'yyyy-mm-dd'),'month')
AND
last_day({?Month})
```

in both halves of the union.

(Also, possibly related question: [Crystal Reports - Oracle 01861 Error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28675021/266304). The code in *this* question is still treating the parameter inconsistently - sometimes as a date, sometimes as a string - so it's relying on NLS settings to work as expected.)

Comment: This looks very promising, the NLS settings in dev have been changed some maybe that is why it is working in dev for me. I will try that code tomorrow and let you know

Comment: You should *really* not rely on NLS settings though. Use actual dates whenever you can, and explicit conversions - where you specify the format model - otherwise. You're doing that in some places, so you just need to carry it through and be consistent.